# Filter by joomla's custom field value

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, filtering

Joomla 3 introduced custom article fields.
I can create one and fill some values in it.
E.g. there is a checkbox that has values **(New, Young, Old)**.

Is it possible to implement filtering of articles based on value of this custom field?
E.g. some way to create a Menu link with this filter (say, for "Old" value only), or any alternative.

Comment: It is possible to implement if you are coder but it will take a lot of work and you will have to hack a lot of Joomla core files, so that you will not be able to update to new versions later. It is much easier to use extensions like Cobalt that does all of that already for ages.